# Should we have a magic-artifact tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

While reading through the questions this morning, I found this one:

[Where Did Dolores Umbridge Get Her Evil Quill?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27679/7603)

While all the current tags are correct, this is specifically about a magic item. It seems like it should be grouped with other questions about magical items even when those aren't part of the Harry Potter franchise. I've seen several Books of Swords questions for which this tag might be appropriate. [magic-weapon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-weapon) might also be a tag synonym for it.

I'm not crazy about "artifact", but both "item" and "object" seem too, I dunno, D&Dish for my tastes.

Answer (score 6):

What purpose does [magic-artifact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-artifact) serve that isn't covered by [magical-items](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-items)?

Comment: That one didn't show up for me as a suggestion when I started typing in "magic". My bad.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than [magical-artifact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-artifact), or even [magical-items](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-items), it may be better to use a more generic [artifact](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artifact). That would cover questions in both science fiction and fantasy genres that involve items in the story.

It may need a better name though. The word artifact may be too obtuse for people to think of when tagging their questions.